# Como conseguir un valor en Cadena SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me explico tengo una cadenas de numeros aun que pareciera fueran parecido no lo son en juego se reprerenta una cadena de la siguiente manera:

```
1881181818181818181800
```

lo que necesito es hacer un select en el segundo par de numeros que seria 81 busqueda del numero 81 detras del primer 18 si lo hiciera asi

```
SELECT Cadena from tabla where cadena like '%81%'
```

de una tabla de mas de 18000 resultados me daria

```
1881181818181818181800
1818181818181818181800
1818181818181818181800
1818181818181818181800

Infinito
```

Siendo una sola fila a recuperar seria la primera pero me muestra los numeros 18 como 81 quiero algo como el subtring(Cadena,3,2) ni idea como seria la consulta para selecionar solo los numeros 3 y 4 de la primera fila que serian 81 Ayuda por favor

Me pidieron me explique mejor creo lo habia hecho:
si hago:

```
SELECT Cadena from tabla where cadena like '%81%'
```

me saldra x cantidad de numeros en vez del 81
cambiando el Valor a uno que mas que OBVIO si mostrara el valor 81 usando el select de arriba

```
138113131313131300
```

lo quiero es para la cadena

```
188118181818181800
```

PD no quiero esto

```
SELECT Cadena from tabla where cadena like '%1881'
```

ni esto

```
SELECT Cadena from tabla where cadena like '%1381'
```

Comment: "lo que necesito es hacer un select en el segundo par de números", qué significa esto?. "Siendo una sola fila a recuperar seria la primera pero me muestra los numeros 18 como 81 quiero algo como el subtring(Cadena,3,2)", y qué significa esto?. Puedes tratar de explicar mejor tu problema?

Comment: ¿Esto no es lo que quieres `SELECT Cadena from tabla where cadena like '1881%'`? ¿Si el número comienza con `'6776'` deberías obtenerla? ¿Cómo eliges los valores de la posiciones 3 y 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de dos maneras:

Utilizando la función [`substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
select Cadena 
  from tabla 
 where substing(Cadena, 3, 2) = '81';
```

Utilizando like:

```
select Cadena 
  from tabla 
 where Cadena like '__81%';
```

Si quieres limitar el resultado siempre a una fila, entonces sería:

```
select top 1 Cadena 
  from tabla 
 where Cadena like '__81%';
```

lo cuál traerá siempre solo la primera fila (aunque haya miles que cumplan con la condición).